# Appium: Is it possible to access dial pad and make call with appium in iOS ?

Tags: ios, mobile, appium

I am trying to access dial pad and make call using appium. Is there a way to do it? I found ways to do in android.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't invoke inbuilt application in iOS using appium. Appium require the Xcode code signing identity(developer mode builds) to invoke applications.